Add custom VSCode style snippets to NVChad
Using Neovim with NVChad.
I have read the documentation but can't get it to work unless I add my custom snippets to the default friendly-snippets folder.
According to the NVChad docs:
-- vscode format i.e json files
vim.g.vscode_snippets_path = "your snippets path"

-- snipmate format 
vim.g.snipmate_snippets_path = "your snippets path"

-- lua format 
vim.g.lua_snippets_path = vim.fn.stdpath "config" .. "/lua/lua_snippets"

These are the relevant files from my project, but nothing makes a difference.
I can see that Neovim is picking up the vscode_snippets_path but it's not loading the custom snippets.
I haven't changed anything else to do with snippets in the configuration.

What am I missing?
